# What default `method` does the `lda()` and `qda()` R functions use?

Tags: r, discriminant-analysis

I am asking this question to help me with [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/506713/163242) bountied question.

The [Wikipedia article for LDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis#Discrimination_rules) describes three discrimination rules: Maximum likelihood, Bayes discriminant rule, and Fisher's linear discriminant rule.

The function definitions for the [`lda()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/MASS/versions/7.3-53/topics/lda) and [`qda()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/MASS/versions/7.3-53/topics/qda) R functions (from the `MASS` package) have a `method` argument:

[image]

However, I cannot find any source that specifies what the default `method` used for these functions is. So what is the default `method` used for these functions? (If you read my bountied question, you'll be able to understand why I'm trying to understand the default `method`.)

Comment: I'd guess it's the first that is mentioned.

Comment: @Lewian perhaps. But what does the first one even mean?

Comment: It means that the standard estimators (sample mean and sample covariance matrix) are plugged into the theoretical population formula for the discriminant functions/decision boundaries.

Comment: @Lewian ahh, yes, I see

Comment: I agree by the way that this is not clearly enough stated on the help page, and you may write to the package maintainer to amend this.

Comment: @Lewian yes, I think that’s a good idea. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is not clearly enough stated on the help page (but maybe in the book), but here is how you can find out: type the R prompt:

```
library(MASS)
 MASS:::lda.default
function (x, grouping, prior = proportions, tol = 1e-04, method = c("moment", 
    "mle", "mve", "t"), CV = FALSE, nu = 5, ...) 
 ...
```

and look at the `method =`  argument. As always in R, the first value mentioned is the default.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It prints out exactly the same thing `function (x, grouping, prior = proportions, tol = 1e-04, method = c("moment", 
    "mle", "mve", "t"), CV = FALSE, nu = 5, ...)`, and then what looks like source code. So the first value in the vector (seems to be `moment`) is the default?

Comment: YES. And, this is the standard way in R, at the prompt, to investigate the source code. Alternatively, to get less output, type ` args(MASS:::lda.default)  `